# SQlite alphabetical order

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, alphabetical

I have an SQlite database with a few categories and each of them have some items inside. Right now the categories are arranged in alphabetical order but I want in the order I put them in the database. Any suggestions? I'm pretty new at this and can't figure it out how to get rid of the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look with simple example:

Table : Categories

`cat_id cat_name someotherValues`

```
  1      A            XYZ
  3      B            UUI
  2      C            8XU
  4      F            6XK
  6      E            9XU
  5      D            7XP
```

Now, if you want it in alphabetical order, you can query like,

`select * from categories order by cat_id`

It'll return you rows in 1,2,3,..,6 of `cat_id` order.

P.S. There's a default `row_id` column created with SQLite tables. You can set order on `row_id` if you haven't any unique field to set order. However order can by set on any field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an autoincremented index. Sort your data using this index and you're set.